# Is it possible with jq to use a deleted value in setting new ones?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, jq

I am using the bash to json parser [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Considering the following command:

```
jq '. * .transitive | del(.transitive) | del(.scope,.scopedName)' package.json > package.github.json$$
```

And the following **input**:

```
{
  "name": "navigation",
  "transitive": {
    "name": "navigation",
    "scope": "bs",
    "scopedName": "@bs/navigation"
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the following **output**:

```
{
  "name": "@bs/navigation"
}
```

Is there a way before doing the delete of `.scopedName`, to use it's value to set `.name`?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a [mcve] with sample input, expected output and actual output to better illustrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have added a sample of input and output.

Comment: Thank you -- that does make this much easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Transforming your input to your output is as simple as:

```
jq '{"name": .transitive.scopedName}'
```

...and of course you could just reorder things to set `name` *before* deleting `transitive`:

```
jq '.name=.transitive.scopedName | del(.transitive)'
```

That said, if you **really** want to use `del()` first, you can save content in a variable and use it later:

```
jq '
  .transitive as $transitive |
  del(.transitive) |
  .name=$transitive.scopedName
'
```

Comment: `jq '. * .transitive | del(.transitive) | .name = .scopedName | del(.scope,.scopedName)'`

Comment: Why go through that extra effort?