# removing one layer of object nesting with JQ

Tags: json, bash, unix, jq, unnest

i have been tinkering with JQ to try and manipulate some data. Thus far, the following JSON output using my command:

```
 map({Row: .[] })
|   map(select(.Row.ganjalord.latitude | test("SOME_TESTING_CONDITION")?))
```

input:

```
[
  {
    "Row": {
      "ganjalord": {
        "latitude": "56.237480",
        "temp": 44
      }
    },
    "fighter": "1"
  },
  {
    "Row": {
      "ganjalord": {
        "latitude": "53.237480",
        "temp": 42
      }
    },
    "fighter": "0"
  }
]
```

how do i achieve the sample output where it is not nested by row?

sample output:

```
[
  {
    "ganjalord": {
      "latitude": "56.237480",
      "temp": 44
    },
    "fighter": "1"
  },
  {
    "ganjalord": {
      "latitude": "53.237480",
      "temp": 42
    },
    "fighter": "0"
  }
]
```

Do i use a simple select statement to try and achieve this ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you for bringing this to my attention, @glennjackman i have updated the q.

Comment: You need to include the **input** so other people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: updated to be input. @glennjackman

Comment: BTW, what you're trying to do here smells quite similar to what the OP was trying to do in another recent question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937290/is-it-possible-with-jq-to-use-a-deleted-value-in-setting-new-ones/50937352.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` operator, given two dictionaries, merges their contents. Thus,

```
jq '[.[] | (. * .Row) | del(.Row)]'
```

...emits as output, when given your input:

```
[
  {
    "fighter": "1",
    "ganjalord": {
      "latitude": "56.237480",
      "temp": 44
    }
  },
  {
    "fighter": "0",
    "ganjalord": {
      "latitude": "53.237480",
      "temp": 42
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems the first pair of parenthesis aren't required

Comment: I consider the code much more readable with them present, however.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the following filter to the "input" as shown, yields the desired result:

```
map( with_entries( if .key == "Row" then .value|to_entries[] else . end) )
```

The key to understanding this is that `with_entries` first applies `to_entries` to yield key/value pairs, and then applies `from_entries`.

Of course, as with a solution based on `. * .Row` or `. * Row` (or `.+.Row` or `.Row+.`), the above solution will entail some loss of data if any of the hoisted key names coincide with the top-level key names.